# Perl better way to exit in a required file

Tags: perl, exit, require, goto, die

I am writing a loader program to decrypt source files and run them. Each source file holds a `Curses::UI` based program which contain subroutines that the user may use to exit the user interface. I need to run some clean up after the user exits though and am not sure how to catch these `exit` or `die` calls so the clean-up code that comes after the required files will execute, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch `die` calls by wrapping the code in an `eval` block, as in:

```
eval {
    require Module::that_dies;
};
if ($@) {
    # handle the exception here
}
```

This won't help for `exit`  though.  You could have code that runs to cleanup after `exit` in an `END{}` block, I believe, but note that this will be run after any exit, not just if your required module exits.

```
END { 
    # code that runs after exit
}

require Module::that_exits;
```

Read more about END blocks in [`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html)

Comment: Wow thanks, I some how totally glossed over the part of perldoc for `exit` that talks about the `END{}` block! Shoving this stuff in there would be great as I can just test to see if the directory the database exists in is there, if not it doesn't need to be played with! Thanks again

Comment: The question needs to be edited before it can be reopened.